# How to setup background image in react

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with a setting up a background image for my React app.

When I'm trying to add a background image it appears in my NavBar.

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
import Background from './Images/BackGround1.jpg'
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar.js';

function Header() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{
      backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`, 
      backgroundPosition: 'top',
      backgroundSize: '100% 100%',
      backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
      }}>
       <Navbar />

         
       
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

How I can add background image and keep the NavBar on top of background image?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have declared styles for the whole div and navbar is inside the same div which makes the background image appear on the Navbar .
Try using

```
<React.Fragment> 
<div className="App" >
</div>
<Navbar />
</React.Fragment>
```